# Connecting to WPA2-Enterprise Wifi Network

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I'm currently trying to connect to my University wifi network and it's of WPA2-Enterprise type.

I found the setup instructions online and I followed them when setting it up using wpa_supplicant.

[image]

The picture above is the settings the school suggests and below is the code I have in my wpa_supplicant.conf file.

[image]

However, I am not able to get internet access even though I am connected.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This guy has the [answer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=353961#p353961):

If you have the cert then this should work for you.

> This is how I did it.
>
> First I grabbed the public certificate that the RADIUS server was offering and saved it as a PEM file.
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir /etc/certs
> sudo cp radius.pem  /etc/certs/
> ```
>
> Then I edited /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
>
> ```
> ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
> network={
>   ssid="MySSID"
>   scan_ssid=1
>   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
>   pairwise=CCMP TKIP
>   group=CCMP TKIP
>   eap=PEAP
>   identity="raspi"
>   password="mypassword"
>   ca_cert="/etc/certs/radius.pem"
>   phase1="peapver=0"
>   phase2="MSCHAPV2"
>   }
> ```
>
> then edited /etc/network/interfaces
>       auto lo
>
> ```
> iface lo inet loopback
> iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> allow-hotplug wlan0
>
> iface wlan0 inet dhcp
>     pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
>     post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
> ```
>
> It sounds simple but it took me a while to crack it. I am also the
>   person who set up the RADIUS server (FreeRADIUS) so I have some inside
>   knowledge. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please provide details on how to get the radius server certificate?

Comment: Try omitting the line starting with `ca_cert=`. On my university's WPA Enterprise network this lets me connect without a certificate.