# Connecting to universities WPA2-Enterprise Wifi Network

Tags: wireless, internet, wpa

As the title suggests, this question is very closely related to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22875/connecting-to-wpa2-enterprise-wifi-network) question. And following the instructions by `Lucas Goossen`, I'm able to get a `inet addr` on my `wlan0` (confirmed by `ifconfig wlan0`), but I dont have an internet connection. In oppose to the original Question, my university doesn't have `ca_cert` (see image below), so I left out that variable. This is my `wpa_supplicant.config` file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="ZHAW"
    scand_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="myidentity"
    password="mypassword"
    phase1="peaplabel=auto pepver=auto"
    phase2="MSCHAPV2"
}
```

The line `phase1="peaplabel=auto pepver=auto"` is from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183766). To be honest, I have no idea whether the variables `pairwise` and `group` are set correctly. So there are a lot of unknowns and I've come nowhere with trial and error.. Can anybody help me here?

[image: wlan configuration]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

English is not my native language so please be patient.

When I don't know how to configure something, sometimes I let the system do it for me, mostly of the times, things works with default values. In this case, if you don't know the function of the `pairwise` and `group` parameters. You could check this [Page](http://www.cs.upc.edu/lclsi/Manuales/wireless/files/wpa_supplicant.conf) or read below:

> pairwise: list of accepted pairwise (unicast) ciphers for WPA CCMP =
>   AES in Counter mode with CBC-MAC [RFC 3610, IEEE 802.11i/D7.0] TKIP =
>   Temporal Key Integrity Protocol [IEEE 802.11i/D7.0] NONE = Use only
>   Group Keys (deprecated, should not be included if APs support pairwise
>   keys) If not set, this defaults to: CCMP TKIP
>
> group: list of accepted group (broadcast/multicast) ciphers for WPA
>   CCMP = AES in Counter mode with CBC-MAC [RFC 3610, IEEE 802.11i/D7.0]
>   TKIP = Temporal Key Integrity Protocol [IEEE 802.11i/D7.0] WEP104 =
>   WEP (Wired Equivalent Privacy) with 104-bit key WEP40 = WEP (Wired
>   Equivalent Privacy) with 40-bit key [IEEE 802.11] If not set, this
>   defaults to: CCMP TKIP WEP104 WEP40

This setup works for me, change it according to your ssid and password (psk)

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp    
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
# ap_scan can be 0, 1, or 2. Some sources say use 2 but 1 work for me.
ap_scan=1
eapol_version=1
network={
        ssid="YOURSSID"
        # This is needed for hidden SSIDs
        scan_ssid=1
        mode=0
        psk="reallylonghexnumber"
        # RSN for WPA2 or WPA for WPA1
        proto=RSN
        # WPA-PSK or WPA-EAP
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        # CCMP for AES or TKIP for TKIP.
        pairwise=CCMP
        # OPEN for WPA1/2 or SHARED or LEAP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

About the line `scan_ssid=1` will be some controversy because some more experimented users don't like the hidden ssid thing, but this works for me.

Hopefully this works for you also.

Sources:

https://linuxtechie.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/setting-up-raspberry-pi-with-wifi-and-a-static-ip-on-a-hidden-ssid/

https://geekytheory.com/tutorial-raspberry-pi-configurar-wif/

http://www.cs.upc.edu/lclsi/Manuales/wireless/files/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: What a beautiful answer, thank you very much! I have yet not been able to apply it and sadly, I wont be able to do it before the weekend. I will definitly do so after the weekend and will accept your question as soon as I've tested it!

Comment: @Ratnanil hope your connection is working now, if not, don't hesitate in update your question or write some comments. Glad to help.

Comment: With the help of your answer and the help of colleague we were able to connect to the school network right this minute! Thank you so much again, I will now accept your answer officially :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to connect to an enterprise wifi following these instructions:
https://gist.github.com/chatchavan/3c58511e3d48f478b0c2

I didn't need a radius server certificate or anything. Key things for Enterprise authentication (MSCHAPV2):

1. add this lines to your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (edit as appropriate):

   ```
   network={
           ssid="YOUR_NETWORK_NAME"
           proto=RSN
           key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
           pairwise=CCMP TKIP
           group=CCMP TKIP
           identity="YOUR_USER_NAME"
           password=hash:YOUR_PASSWORD_HASH
           phase1="peaplabel=0"
           phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
   }
   ```
2. add this lines to your `/etc/network/interface` (edit as appropriate):

   ```
   auto wlan0
   allow-hotplug wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
       post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
   ```
3. try bringing the network interface down and up again:

   ```
   sudo ifdown wlan0
   sudo up wlan0
   ```
4. The following error message should be ignored. It's a known bug upstream from Debian.

   ```
   ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
   ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
   ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
   ```
5. If there's no error, you should be able to see the wireless adapter connected with the following command `iwconfig`. The output will show the SSID and other connection info:

   ```
   wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"YOUR_NETWORK_NAME"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
             Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
             Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
   ```
6. You should check if you have an IP address with the following command: `ifconfig`. The wlan0 entry should have an IP address, like the following.

   ```
   ...
   wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
             inet addr:192.168.0.110  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:497 errors:0 dropped:32 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:83237 (81.2 KiB)  TX bytes:60068 (58.6 KiB)
   ...
   ```

Comment: Do not do this! I cannot comment on the `wpa_supplicant.conf` but the `/etc/network/interface` is **OBSOLETE** (also has errors even for the obsolete setting). See[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: What are the errors? What do you mean by obsolete? Should it not be done? What should it be done instead?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer here. Basically we need to downgrade the wpasupplicant to stretch version v2.4
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244731#p1498661